# Replacing string with value calculated from the max of another column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with an ID column that has dtype Object (as contains INTs and STRs) so am trying to use `np.where` to replace each of them in turn with the next highest number... However for some reason in the example below it's only replacing one of the 2 strings and I have no idea why?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'IDstr':['480610_ABC_087', '78910_ABC_087','4806105017087','414149'],
                       'IDint':[ 0, 0, 4806105017087, 414149]})
print (df)
```

```
unique_str_IDs = df['IDstr'][df['IDstr'].str.contains("ABC", na=False)].unique()
for i in range(len(unique_str_IDs)):
    df['SKUintTEST']=np.where(df['IDstr'] == unique_str_IDs[i].strip(), 
            df['SKUint_y'].max()+i+1, df['SKUint_y'])
```

Has anyone got any ideas?

Comment: the problem is you overwrite the column `df['SKUintTEST']` at each loop. So it works for each unique ID but your code keeps only the last iteration at the end

Comment: I think it updated based on a match for first item in array - and then second. How do I avoid this? (Thanks for your help Ben.T )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with a dictionary created with in incremental for each unique id, then `fillna` with the original value for the rows not mapped:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'IDstr':['480610_ABC_087', '78910_ABC_087','4806105017087','414149'],
                    'IDint':[ 0, 0, 4806105017087, 414149], 
                    'SKUint_y': range(10,14)})

unique_str_IDs = df.loc[df['IDstr'].str.contains("ABC", na=False), 'IDstr'].unique()

df['SKUintTEST'] = df['IDstr'].map({idx:i for i, idx in enumerate(unique_str_IDs, df.SKUint_y.max()+1)})\
                              .fillna(df.SKUint_y)

print (df)
            IDstr          IDint  SKUint_y  SKUintTEST
0  480610_ABC_087              0        10        14.0
1   78910_ABC_087              0        11        15.0
2   4806105017087  4806105017087        12        12.0
3          414149         414149        13        13.0
```

Comment: Thank you Ben.T!! Just what I needed